# Getting values from parent class to child class from an instance

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, parent-child

I have a person class with a `$name` property and an officer class with an `$officer_name` property. I need to be able to get the `$name` property from the person class to the officer class. In this case it should have an output of "Major Blake". Do I need to make an instance of the officer class for me to be able to echo this out?

```
class person {
    protected $name;

    private function set_name($fv_name) {       
        $this->name = $fv_name;
    }

    public function get_name() {        
        return $this->name;
    }

    function __construct($fv_name) {        
        $this->set_name($fv_name);
    }
}

class officer extends person {

    private function give_rank(){
        return "Major ";
    }

    function __construct() {        
        echo $officer_name = $this->give_rank() . parent::get_name();
    }
}

$iv_person = new person("Blake");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code :
your class :

```
<?php
class person {
    protected $name;

    private function set_name($fv_name) {       
        $this->name = $fv_name;
    }

    public function get_name() {        
        return $this->name;
    }

    function __construct($fv_name) {        
        $this->set_name($fv_name);
    }
}

class officer extends person {

    private function give_rank(){
        return "Major ";
    }

    function __construct($fv_name) {
        parent::__construct($fv_name);
    }

    function output(){      
        return $this->give_rank().parent::get_name();
    }
}
```

your call :

```
$iv_person = new officer("Blake");  
echo $iv_person->output();
```